# Showing $S^2/{\sim}$ (real projective plane) is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $\pi:\;S^2\to S^2/{\sim}$ be the projection map where the relation on $S^2$ is $a\sim b\iff a =\pm b$. I am trying to show $S^2/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff.

So take $\alpha,\beta\in S^2/{\sim}$ then $\pi^{-1}(\alpha)=\{\pm a\},\pi^{-1}(\beta)=\{\pm b\}$. Take $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}\min\left\{\|a-b\|, \|a+b\|\right\}$ then $A=B_\varepsilon(a)\cap S^2, B=B_\varepsilon(b)\cap S^2$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $a,b$ (and $-A,-B$ for $-a,-b$). Now $\pi(A)\cap\pi(B)=\emptyset$ since $\pi(u)=\pi(v)\iff u=\pm v$ and $A,B$ disjoint.

But I can't see how to properly show that $\pi(A),\pi(B)$ are open? I know that not all projection maps are open maps so it's not immediate...

Comment: The fibers of $\pi$ are discrete, some $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Is not hard to see that $\pi$ is a covering map so it need to be an open map.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms fibers or covering map, I am still towards the start of my course. Is there a straightforward way to prove this?

Comment: Note that the following look typographically different from each other: $$ \begin{align} & S^2/\sim \\ & S^2/{\sim} \end{align} $$ Notice how they are coded. There is a reason why it works that way, and a reason why it _ought_ to work that way. I corrected this in my edit to the question.

Comment: The symbol $\cap$ is used in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n,$ and $\bigcap$ is used in things like $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k.$ I changed several instances of $\bigcap$ to $\cap$ in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of the quotient topology, $\pi(A)$ is open iff $\pi ^{-1}(\pi(A))$ is open. But this is just $A \cup -A$, which is a union of two open sets. Similarly for $B$.